# Github prepends "https://github.com/user/repo/blob/main/" to all links in readme.md

Tags: github, git-lfs

I have a private repository on GitHub that contains a readme.md file with links to Kaggle datasets. When viewing the repo on github prepends "https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/blob/main/" to the url, breaking it.

Why is this happening, and how do I change this behavior?

For what it's worth, I'm also using git-lfs, though I can't find any documentation of this behavior associated with that, either.

Comment: Hope this helps : [What does “blob” in Github correspond to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047434/what-does-blob-in-github-correspond-to)

Comment: Why is it "wrong"?  What do you want to change it _to_?

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute URLs in your links?  Can you show us an example of the Markdown that's problematic in a code block in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out on my own. The URL was missing a scheme, and github was treating it like a relative link to something in the repository. This was my mistake and not an issue with github.